# Как связать многие ко многим не по ID

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

2 сущности House и City и скриншот БД. Сейчас понял, что не совсем корректно связал, потому что когда пользователь делает запрос, то ему необходимо вбивать цифру, а не название, города, что не является правильным. Как мне правильно связать, чтобы когда происходит запрос, то в House добавлялось название города и имело связи с City?

City

```
@Data
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Table(name = "city", schema = "public")
public class City {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.REFRESH
}, mappedBy = "city")
@ToString.Exclude
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private Set<House> house;

@Column(name = "id_region", nullable = false)
private Integer id_region;
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;
}
```

House

```
@Data
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Table (name = "house", schema = "public")
public class House {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private City city;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "house")
    private Set<Contract> contract;

    @Column(name = "id_landlord", nullable = false)
    private Long id_landlord;
    @Column(name = "outside", nullable = false)
    private String outside;
    @Column(name = "rooms", nullable = false)
    private Integer rooms;
    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    private Double price;
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private Status status;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не понял, какая связь между тем, что вбивает юзер в UI и тем, как вы храните даные? Делайте такой UI, который считаете нужным и готовьте все необходимые данные для запроса в коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Связывать сущности в БД нужно (за редким исключением) по id. Откуда `id` возьмется в коде, который, скажем, создает `House` это другой вопрос, и сейчас его рассмотрим.

Действительно, обычно пользователь не вводит `id`, так как это неудобно. Но и задавать имя города в текстовом поле, тоже не дружественно к пользователю, и так не делают. Что будет, например, если пользователь сделает опечатку?

Важно то, что пользователь не задает произвольный город. Если в `House` хранится ссылка на город (прямо или через промежуточную таблицу - не важно), то пользователь *выбирает* из существующих городов.

На практике это значит, что система дает пользователю выбор города. Это может быть либо выпадающий список, либо инкрементный поиск с подтверждением выбора, либо поиск по критериям опять же с подтверждением выбора. Существенно тут то, что в UI пользователь видит точное название города, то что этот город в принципе доступен для выбора. При самом же выборе, программа использует `id` выбранного города, для создания `House`.

Поэтому конкретная реализация зависит от того, что у вас используется в UI. В БД, сервисе и даже MVC контроллере, нужно использовать `id`.